# Ruby SmarterCSV gem keep blank strings

Tags: ruby, smartercsv

The [SmarterCSV wiki page for Basics](https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv/wiki/The-Basics) says that it's possible to retain blank strings for columns that don't have any data (consecutive commas), but I couldn't find additional information on how to do that.

I assume it's something to do with the data validations step, but I can't figure out what. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't played with this gem but it looks like you have a few options that you can pass in:

```
:downcase_header
:strings_as_keys
:remove_zero_values
:remove_values_matching
:remove_empty_hashes
:convert_values_to_numeric
```

In this case, looks like you might want to set `remove_empty_values` to false. This works in the last v1 (1.2.6) version of the gem.

In v2, which is still in pre-release, the format is to use the `hash_transformations` option to the `process` method, and to set it as follows: `[:none, :strip_spaces]` This first turns off all transformations and then turns on the ones you want, so in this case, the removal of blank values is now turned off.

Comment: Your answer is almost correct - the option to change for what I wanted is `remove_empty_values` and it needs to be set to `false`. The relevant code is in `lib/smarter_csv/smarter_csv.rb` in the gem. I am happy to mark your answer the right one if you can make that change.

Comment: @sameers Updated answer